# How to pseudorandomize a vector with probabilistic constraints?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have numbers 1 through 5. I need each number to appear 24 times (so my whole list should be 120 numbers long). I need there to be no consecutive repeats (4 cannot follow 4). I also need each number to follow each other only 25% of each time they occur (5 should follow 4 six times).

How can I do this in R? I tried sampling 1 through 5 twenty-four times and then arranging them but there has to be a smarter way! I feel like a for loop or something? I am at a loss and feel like here is an easy solution I am not seeing.

Thank you!

```
# There are 5 different items I am trying to order
   Trips = c(1:5)

# Each set of 5 needs to appear 24 times, so inefficiently making it 24 times 
  T1 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T2 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T3 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T4 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T5 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T6 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T7 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T8 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T9 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T10 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T11 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T12 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T13 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T14 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T15 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T16 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T17 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T18 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T19 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T20 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T21 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T22 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T23 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)
  T24 <- sample(Trips, replace = FALSE)


# Combining the triplets made above into one stream
  Stream_T <- c(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, 
                T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24)


   df <- as.data.frame(Stream_T)

# Checking how often each number follows each other
  cbind(ahead = lead(df$Stream_T), df$Stream_T, behind = lag(df$Stream_T))
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to create every permutation of 1-5 and then randomly order the permutations.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit:

Although this is not a solution (for reasons shown below) I'll leave it as a starting point, in case soemone else want's to give it a try. Feel free to demand deletion in a comment and I will do so

Since you mention `for` loop in your question, here is a possible solution using a loop:

Setup information:

```
set.seed(124)
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
total_length <- 120
```

Initialize result vector with a first randomly drawn value

```
result <- sample(numbers, 1)
```

Now iterate for the remaining values, and each iteration exclude the last element in the result list (so we **can't** draw the same number)

```
for (i in 1:(total_length -1 )) {
  allowed <- numbers[numbers != result[length(result)]]
  result <- c(result, sample(allowed, 1))
}
```

The result *should* have all the desired characteristics, but maybe the sample size is to small for the "law of large numbers" to kick in ;)

Let's test:

Condition 'I need there to be no consecutive repeats (4 cannot follow 4)'

```
all((lag(result,default = 10) - result) != 0)
all((lead(result,default = 10) - result) != 0)
```

Return both:

```
[1] TRUE
```

So far so good, but:

Condition 'I need each number to appear 24 times'

```
table(result)
```

Returns:

```
result
1  2  3  4  5 
24 26 24 25 21
```

-> the condition is not met!